# How do I view the SQL generated by SubSonic SimpleRepository?

Tags: c#, sql, subsonic

I've got this toy code, works fine, using MySQL

```
  var r = new SimpleRepository("DB", SimpleRepositoryOptions.None);
  var q = r.Find<User>(x => x.UserName ==  "testuser");
```

How do I view the SQL generated by that query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately using SimpleRepository you can't do what you want without stepping into the SubSonic code. Because the Find method returns an IList it's executed before you get the chance to evaluate the SQL that's going to be executed. There are efforts underway to add this functionality in future versions of SubSonic but until then you're probably best looking at the [MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html).

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, you can always run [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to see the queries.

Comment: +1 Just what I was going to suggest - has the advantage that you're guaranteed to see what is sent to the server.

Comment: Would be great, however as mentioned I do not use SQL server.

Comment: There's a previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124925/is-there-a-tool-like-microsofts-sql-server-profiler-for-mysql), about a MySQL equivalent for this tool.  Unfortunately, the accepted answer was "No, there is no such tool."

Comment: So subsonic does not have a knob anywhere that lets it spew out the string it generates ? :-(

Comment: There is a Log property on the IDataProvider, but I can't figure out how to use it with the SimpleRepository. (And I don't know if it works either)